# Unable to connect to MS SQL Server with PHP through Windows Authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-authentication

I've been having problems connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database through Windows Authentication using the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$serverName = "sql";
$options = array("Database" => "db_name");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

if($conn == false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

?>
```

I get the following error message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\TOMHANKS$'.1

When I connect to MS SQL Server through the Management Studio with Windows Authentication, I log-in as DOMAIN\tom.hanks.

From what I understand, the identity that is used to connect to the server will always be the identity of the process in which PHP is running.  How do I change this identity such that it is the same as my Windows log-in?  Thanks.

Comment: use `runas` to run as a different user?

Comment: I don't have admin privileges to restart the process under a different username. I don't think changing the process username is the way to go either because when I publish the application, I need people on the local network to be able to access the database using their Windows account also.

Comment: I just don't understand why the sqlsrv_connect() method will not connect me with my Windows credentials, since it connects via Windows Authentication

Comment: generally speaking, you should never allow end-users to have direct login-privs on your database. If they had MSSMS installed, they could log into the db and bypass all the logic of your app and directly mangle data.

Comment: then if it's all shared data and not requiring any particular security, why not use sqlserver authentication and embed those credentials in your app?

Comment: yeah I could do that. the system admin set up the database so that everybody right now connects through Windows Authentication, so it'd be nice to follow that. however, I could definitely ask the admin to set up a SQL Server Authentication log-in as a temporary solution.  thanks for the idea